# Batch script to replace .otf file names with title

Tags: batch, batch-file, rename

I'm new to batch files, scripts and all that stuff, unfortunately I don't really know anything about it, but I have this problem and I haven't found a solution yet.

I'm using windows 10 and I have a bunch of .otf files which name has been replaced with numbers. The actual name of every font is written in the title tag.

Is there a way to replace each file's name with the respective title?

Comment: Sure it is possible, but we need to see examples of a small set of before and after, and also [edit] to include some things you've tried so we see you took a stab at it with your own effort and not just asking for us to do it for you entirely. You're heard that SU is not a script writing service or if not, you will hear that so take my advice and [edit] accordingly with some of that detail.

Comment: I understand, but the thing is that I don't really know anything about computer language so I wouldn't be able to do this kind of stuff on my own.

I knew batch scripts existed yesterday when I found a way to compress multiple folders to multiple .zip files all at once, without having to do it by myself.

Now I need to rename these .otf files, and I've found out that there are many programs (like mp3tag) that are able to solve this problem, but only using multimedia files like .mp3, not .otf

Comment: Federico - No worries.... simply try one of those tools such as mp3tag after reading over and confirming the product will do what you need, and then do some quick reading over the process, take a stab at it even it thru a GUI, [edit] this question you started with some of this detail, screen shots, etc. of what you try and have trouble with and what you are trying to accomplish. Just show something you have tried so even if it is way off, this will be proof you are trying. You may then get a better solution but show your attempt that fails and explain clearly what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Federico - Look here for a starting point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298447/access-music-file-metadata-in-powershell and try running it from `PowerShell ISE` that you click on from Windows 10. If you can use that and give a failed PowerShell attempt a try and show me what you tried and the issue, I can probably help you resolve. I'd go with a PowerShell compatible solution and try to not use batch if possible. I know batch and I know PowerShell, go PowerShell whenever you can; way more robust in almost all cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can complete this task by using exiftool for windows + batch script.

1. Download [Exiftool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) for Windows
2. If you downloaded the zip file extract and Rename exiftool(-k).exe to exiftool.exe
3. Press Windows + R to open the run command and run this to open the variables managing Window:

   rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables

Add the location where you saved exiftool.exe to the %path% variable so you can run it from anywhere in the command prompt without having to specify the full path of the program every time you use it.

4. Create this batch and adapt it to your needs:

   @echo off

   SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

   Rem Specify here the path where your fonts are:

   set FontsPath=C:\Users\Ricardo\Downloads\Fonts\New

   for %%a in (%FontsPath%*) do (

   for /f "Delims=" %%b in ('exiftool -s3 -FontName "%%a"') do ren "%%a" "%%b%%~xa"

   )

   echo.

   pause

[image]